# Get Exact Number of Days Between Certain Months Using DATEDIFF() Not Giving Expected Results

Tags: sql-server, datediff

The following is sample data:

```
NewReportDate | Age      | OldReportDate
-----------------------------------------
2014-04-28    |31.558767 | 2014-03-28
2014-04-28    |13-438767 | 2014-03-28
2014-04-28    |13.198767 | 2014-03-28
```

The following is my query:

```
SELECT 
Q.Type
,Q.Oper
,Q.SNo
,Q.Hours
,CONVERT(Date, Q.ReportDate + '28', 112) AS 'Report_Date'
, a.*
, (DATEDIFF(dy, CONVERT(Date, Q.ReportDate + '28', 112),A.ReportDate )/365) + A.age AS 'AdjustedAge'
FROM QReport Q
INNER JOIN AReport a
ON q.name = a.name 
WHERE a.ReportDate = '2014-03-28 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY A.ReportDate desc
```

The following are my results:

```
NewReportDate | Age      | OldReportDate | AdjustedAge|
-------------------------------------------------------
2014-04-28    |31.558767 | 2014-03-28    |31.558767 
2014-04-28    |13.438767 | 2014-03-28    |13.438767
2014-04-28    |13.198767 | 2014-03-28    |13.198767
```

Why is my `AdjustedAge` not changing when there is a month difference between `NewReportDate` and `OldReportDate`?

There should be a difference in the decimal.

Comment: what is in QReport and in AReport? the sample data is not useful

Comment: qReportSample data is Converted from a string date '201404'.  How is this not useful.  The only thing that is wrong is the result of the `AdjustedAge`

Comment: @Fredou Didn't mean to sound rude...its been a very long day...Its always a pain when customers send you bad data...what kind of sample data would make this more useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 31 days between 2014-04-28 and 2014-03-28.

31 / 365 using integer division = 0

0 + x = x

Therefore the two value are identical. Consider dividing by 365.26 instead.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. Sorry if that was misleading, I was just saying the technically correct number of days in a year.